# Web page garbled (encoding?) when downloading from within PHP

Tags: php, html, http, encoding, download

I am trying to download this page (http://www.360.ru/) from within PHP. However, when I write the file out and view it, the content is garbled/corrupt. However, a different page from the same site downloads with out problems (http://www.360.ru/goods/category/3/466/). And both work perfect well within Chrome & Firefox (which both report the encoding is UTF-8). I can not think what the problem can be. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('/temp/out.html', fopen("http://www.360.ru/", 'r'));
file_put_contents('/temp/out2.html', fopen("http://www.360.ru/goods/category/3/466/", 'r'));
exit;
?>
```

When I open the two files, "out.html" is garbled, corrupt and "out2.html" is perfectly okay. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, I downloaded the two web pages from within Chrome - the file size of the page that works is exactly the same as the corresponding PHP download ("out2.html"), but the "out.html" file is only 18.5Kb, but should be 76.3Kb - It seems that PHP is failing to correctly download "http://www.360.ru/" - Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, figured it out - the first page was gzipped. Using gzopen instead of fopen fixed the problem. Hope this helps others...